# Latex: Header and section titles with background

Tags: latex, header, background

I want to make a latex template similar to this:
http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/9599/cat.png
Header and section title has a grey background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using TikZ and the current page node. Here are examples: [Fancy chapter headings with TikZ](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/).